# DRY method of snapshotting an object state

Tags: c++

Consider the following:

```
template <class T>
struct C {
    T a, b, c;   
};

struct CSnapshot : public C<float> {};
struct CRealtime : public C<const float*> {
    CRealtime() {
        // Pointers are bound to some mutable data   
    }

    void snapshotInto(CSnapshot& snapshot) {
        snapshot.a = *a;
        snapshot.b = *b;
        snapshot.c = *c;
    }
};
```

Is there any good way to make the `snapshotInto` method above DRYer? So, for example, if `d` is added, there is no option of forgetting to snapshot its state in the `snapshotInto` method, or accidentally snapshotting the realtime `c` value into it.

Motivation: This sort of code may be needed, for example, if you have an audio rendering thread which uses some parameters, which may change on a different thread due to user interaction. To make use of the parameters in your audio rendering thread, you need to be sure the parameter values don't change under your feet, so you make a snapshot of the realtime variables at the beginning of the render callback, each time it is called.

P.S. I'm not stuck on the above implementation; for example, if there is a DRY way which works if you put the realtime pointer and the snapshotted value into a struct, for example, that's fine; *however*, there should still be a way to get an interface similar to that of the `CSnapshot` object, so given an object `snapshot` the user can just write `snapshot.a` to get the snapshotted float value, and doesn't have to write e.g. `snapshot.a.getVal()`.

P.P.S. Performance is paramount, so having to access a map by key, for example, to get at either the snapshot value or the realtime pointer, won't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for some sort of *static reflection*, which is not available *(yet)* in C++. Here's a solution that uses [`BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-Struct.html#gab9efb238a82207d91643994c5295cf8c):

```
template <typename T> 
struct C {
    BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(C,
        (T, a),
        (T, b),
        (T, c)
    );
};


struct CSnapshot : public C<float> {};
struct CRealtime : public C<const float*> 
{
    void snapshotInto(CSnapshot& snapshot) 
    {
        constexpr auto snapshot_accessors = boost::hana::accessors<CSnapshot>();
        constexpr auto realtime_accessors = boost::hana::accessors<CRealtime>();
        constexpr auto range = boost::hana::make_range(
            boost::hana::int_c<0>, boost::hana::size(realtime_accessors));

        boost::hana::for_each(range, [&](auto i)
        {
            auto snapshot_getter = boost::hana::second(snapshot_accessors[i]);
            auto realtime_getter = boost::hana::second(realtime_accessors[i]);
            snapshot_getter(snapshot) = *(realtime_getter(*this));
        });
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    float a=1, b=2, c=3;

    CSnapshot cs;
    CRealtime cr{{&a, &b, &c}};

    cr.snapshotInto(cs);
    assert(cs.a == a);
    assert(cs.b == b);
    assert(cs.c == c);
}
```

[**full wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/1rodqZqFtXwo08MQ)

---

The above example is compiled to the following assembly with **g++ 7.0.0 20160825** on Win x64, using `-Ofast -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti`:

```
main:
    subq    $40, %rsp
    call    __main
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $40, %rsp
    ret
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Boost.Hana`, is there any runtime overhead for using this technique?

Comment: @Danra: no. I updated my answer with the generated assembly. `Boost.Hana` can be used for arbitrary **compile-time** computations :)

Comment: Also is there a way to get the wandbox example to work with std=c++14?

Comment: Well, that was obvious... :) Thanks!

Comment: There are a couple of mechanisms that seem to almost do what I want without needing reflection: variadic templates (which would work if a POD struct could be automatically decomposed to its elements - I'm not aware that it can be) and the upcoming structured bindings, which *do* support decomposing POD structs, but just not in a variadic way (so it would work if it were possible to write something like `auto [a, ...] = cs;`)